# What's the difference: ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer vs HttpSolrServer vs CommonsHttpSolrServer?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, information-retrieval

What are the differences between the following implementations of [SolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer.html):

1. `ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer`
2. `HttpSolrServer`
3. `CommonsHttpSolrServer` (Note: Is this now deprecated?)

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.html):

> It is only recommended to use ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer with /update requests. The class HttpSolrServer is better suited for the query interface.

The documentation for ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer suggests using it for updates and HttpSolrServer for queries. Why is this?

At the moment I am using `HttpSolrServer` for everything, will using `ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer` for updates result in significant performance improvements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are currently in 2017, and Solr community renamed `SolrServer` into [SolrClient](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_1_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrClient.html) and currently we have 4 implementations:

1. `CloudSolrClient`
2. `ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient`
3. `HttpSolrClient`
4. `LBHttpSolrClient`

Documentation suggests to use `ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient`, because it buffers all update requests into `final BlockingQueue<Update> queue;`, so operation time on updates will be less than using `HttpSolrClient`, which behaves like this - as soon as it gets update request it immediately fires it. Of course, we are trusting the documentation, but it will be so easy to get this answer, that's why I did some perf testing.

However, first I will describe the different operations of the clients. If you're using `add` operation of the SolrClient, there is no difference if you gonna create `HttpSolrClient` or `ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient`, cause both methods will do the same. `ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient` only shines if you're explicitily doing `UpdateRequest`

Test results for indexing wikipedia titles ([code](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene7/src/main/scala/WikiIndexingTest.scala)):
My machine is: Intel i5-4670S 3.1 Ghz 16 Gb RAM

```
ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient (5 threads, 1000 queue size) - 200 seconds    
ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient (5 threads, 10000 queue size) - 150 seconds    
ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient (10 threads, 1000 queue size) - 100 seconds    
ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient (10 threads, 10000 queue size) - 30 seconds    
HttpSolrClient (no bulk) - 7000 seconds    
HttpSolrClient (bulk 1000 docs) - 150 seconds    
HttpSolrClient (bulk 10000 docs) - 80 seconds
```

Summary:

1. If you're using clients in similar fashion, e.g: `client.add(doc);` than, `ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient` performing at least 10-20 times faster, because of the usage of ThreadPool and Queue (aka Bulk operation)
2. If you're using `HttpSolrClient`, you still could mimic this behaviour, by manually creating several clients, running additional threads and using some intermediate storage, like List. It will improve the performance for sure, but requires additional code.
3. Numbers most likely have very little sense, but I hope it gives some raw comparison.